# Apache Pig join returns empty relation

Tags: apache-pig

```
cust_joined = JOIN cust_filtered BY (LOW, HIGH, NORMAL), cust_conversion BY (Low, High, Normal);
```

When Datatypes are chararray for all these fields.

cust_filtered includes the following entries -- I stored this relation and these are in that file:

```
cust_id           Val1      Val2     Year      Low  High  Normal  Prod-code
1925635222        16.2      61.2     2013      null null  <=6.9   1234548-5
9253821456        16.8      65.8     2014      null null  <7.0    4548567-9
```

Sample entries within cust_conversion -- I stored this relation and these are in that file:

```
Low     High   Normal     Cust-Session     Price
null    null    <=6.9      ABC-1234        16.9
null    null    <=7.0      PQR-4567        87.0
```

Unfortunately cust_joined relation is empty. Any help with this will be great

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why its not working for you, it worked for me. Can you paste your pig script.

```
cust_filtered = LOAD 'cust_filtered.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') AS(cust_id:long,Val1:float,Val2:float,Year:chararray, LOW:chararray, HIGH:chararray, NORMAL:chararray, Prod_code:chararray);
cust_conversion = LOAD 'cust_conversion.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (Low:chararray, High:chararray, Normal:chararray, Cust_Session:chararray, Price:float);
cust_joined = JOIN cust_filtered BY (LOW, HIGH, NORMAL), cust_conversion BY (Low, High, Normal);
DUMP cust_joined;

OUTPUT:
(1925635222,16.2,61.2,2013,null,null,<=6.9,1234548-5,null,null,<=6.9,ABC-1234,16.9)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that where you have null in your data, you have actual pig values `null`, is that correct?

If so, than this would be the reason, as pig inner joins ignore null keys:

```
The JOIN operator always performs an inner join. Inner joins ignore null keys, so it makes sense to filter them out before the join.
```

See http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#join-inner

If these are chararrays with `"null"` as a value, than this should basically work, as mentioned in the other answer.